# Material changes from editor script are lost on save

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am changing a material texture in an editor script. Once run, I can see the changes in the editor window, but when I save my scene or hit play, the changes are lost.

Here is my code:

```
var mySkyBox = Resources.Load<Material>("Materials/MySkyBox");
Undo.RecordObject(mySkyBox, "setting mySkyBox texture");  
var texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
texture.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes("texturePath"));
mySkyBox.SetTexture("_UpTex", texture);  
EditorUtility.SetDirty(mySkyBox);
```

I have also tried using `LoadMainAssetAtPath` to load the material but that does not work either.

I am using Unity **5.3.7f1**

How I can correctly edit a material in an editor script and have the changes persist?

Comment: EditorSceneManager.MarkAllScenesDirty() also does not work

Comment: Hey, it sounds interesting that unity does not save it after you call `SetDirty`. But you can try to call `AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();` - it might help.
You can also try to use `AssetDatabase` to load an asset:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Material tempSkyBox = Resources.Load<Material>("Materials/MySkyBox");
// this will make a copy from the loaded material

tempSkyBox.SetTexture("_MainTex",(Texture2D) AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("texturePath", typeof(Texture2D)));
// Sets the main texture on the copy of the material that you just made
// Make sure that the image file is located somewhere in the unityproject folder

AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(tempSkyBox, "materialPath" + "/mySkybox.mat");
// Saves the copy of the material to the disk

AssetDatabase.Refresh(ImportAssetOptions.ForceSynchronousImport);
// force the editor to update the AssetsFolder

myCamera.GetComponentInChildren<Skybox>().material = tempSkyBox;
// Sets the reference
```

this method worked for me in one of my projects
Good luck ^^